# Speed, distance, time problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A woman drives a distance of 40 km to work each day, her average speed is v km/h. If she increases her average speed by 5 km/h, her trip is 2 minutes shorter in time than her normal time.
What is her normal speed in km/h?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $\text{speed}=\dfrac{\text{distance}}{\text{time}}$.

Hence, assuming that the woman's workplace is $40$km away, and her average speed for this journey $v$ km/h, the average time is takes for her to get to work is: $\quad t=\dfrac{40}{v}$.

Now if she travels 5 km/h faster, cutting 2 minutes ($\frac{1}{30}$ hours), the equation for $t$ becomes: $$t-\frac{1}{30}=\frac{40}{v+5}.$$

I.E: $$\frac{40}{v}=\frac{40}{v+5}+\frac{1}{30}.$$

Solving for $v$ yields $v=75$.

Comment: That is really helpful, thank you

Answer (score 0):

So you can see she will travel 40/v hours normally. So then increase by 5 so v+5. then time is 40/(v+5) hours. 2 minutes=1/30 hours, so we having 40/v=40/(v+5)+1/30 so v=75,-80 but speed is positive so v=75 km/h.

Confirming: normal speed 75 km/h with distance 40 km so final time=40/75=8/15 hrs=32 minutes. sped up speed=75+5=80 km/h with distance 40 km so final time=40/80=1/2 hrs.=30 minutes. 32-30=2 minutes so it is correct.